# Is there an easy way to turn columns-to-text without CONCATENATE in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm aware of the text-to-columns button. Can the opposite be done by selecting columns, and possibly running a macro or using a similar button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally I say "Please post your code" for help/assistance writing macros, but this one is really, really simple.

```
Public Function ColumnsToText(rng As Range, Optional DelimitBy As String = " ") As String
'Applies on a row/partial row of data. Must be continuous cells, e.g., A1:D1.
Dim var As Variant

var = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Value))
    ColumnsToText = Join(var, DelimitBy)

End Function
```

ENter it in a worksheet cell like:

`=ColumnsToText(A1:F1)`

Or you can specify an optional delimiter, it is a space by default, but you could use any string characters:

`=ColumnsToText(A1:F1,"%")`

[image]

Etc.

Comment: Nice! that was a new one to me. But why the double transpose? I saw that a single gives an error, but why does it solve it to do it twice?

Comment: In checking it out I saw that putting a range to a variant always creates a 2-dimensional array even if we only have a single row or column. If I use a single transpose it turns a single row into a single column or vice versa; but it is still a 2 dimensional array. By using a double transpose we end up with a 1-dimensional array which is needed for the Join to work. But why does a double transpose not simply reverse the orientation twice? What is happening with that?

Comment: @D_Bester not really sure *why* it works that way, but it does. Must be something unique about a vector array, the first transpose turns an array of 1 row, n Columns, in to an array of n Rows, 1 column.  The second transpose turns an array with 1 column in to a vector array, rather than a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: This is clean and useful...I like! I'm new to writing in the "Optional" statement into a function; good one. Special reason for "Public"?

Comment: This worked great David! Much better than trying to reverse the text-to-column button somehow. Any advice on a quick way to store the Public function for future spreadsheets?

Comment: I don't think it matters of you declare the function "public", just as long as you don't declare it "private".

Comment: To make this function, and others,  available in other workbooks, create a PERSONAL.XLSB/PERSONAL.XLS file.  And store your common macros/functions in that file.   Google for this information,  it needs to be saved in a specific folder but then Excel still always open it.  Or you may be able to create an XLAM addin file for the same puprose.

Comment: If you have trouble with either,  post a new Q and I'll try to help out when I'm back in front of a computer.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get the same CSV string which Excel will generate for each row, when saving as CSV file? For example, cells with embedded commas will be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: @allsolutions yes.  Ask a new question though... you should be able to do this using standard I/O methods to write file...

Comment: Already posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680594/convert-multiple-excel-sheets-to-csv-string-in-memory-or-single-csv-file-using-c. Can you please reply there?

Comment: @allsolutions well seeing as it's Saturday evening and I'm busy with my family, probably I will not respond, but someone else may.  I would mention that it's somewhat presumptuous to expect me to answer your questions by request... SO is a site I participate on for *free* and on my own time.

Comment: Ya I understand. Since you responded, hence I requested as finding it difficult to get responses on weekend. Of course, you can deny the request :)

Comment: @allsolutions you might improve the chances of getting answers (now, or in a day or two) if you demonstrate what you've tried so far in terms of code...

Comment: I believe the question is quite detailed, but in terms of tried approaches, my question is exactly on which code approach is suitable.

Answer (score 4):

I was intrigued by the answer @David Zemens gave using a double transpose. His answer works well. I did found one other way to get a single row into a 1 dimensional array. Also I wanted a function that could handle a column. So here is my alternate answer.

```
Public Function ColumnOrRowToText(rng As Range, Optional DelimitBy As String = " ") As String
    'rng must be a single row or a single column; cannot handle multiple columns or rows

    Dim var As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        var = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rng.Value, 1, 0) 'for a single row
    Else
        var = Application.Transpose(rng.Value) 'for a single column
    End If

    'var must be a 1 dimensional array
    ColumnOrRowToText = Join(var, DelimitBy)

End Function
```

Comment: Although this doesn't exactly match the question, it still is useful to consider. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the true reverse of Text-to-Columns is the formula TEXTJOIN. It will return your selected column entries into one cell in one long string separated by a delimeter that you can set on your own.

[image: TEXT JOIN example]

Comment: New in Excel 2016 I believe. Certainly seems the simplest answer

Answer (score 1):

If instead what you're interested in is "unpivoting" your column to be values in their own column, then essentially you need to create a flat file.

This is best accomplished with R' "gather" function or Python Pandas' "melt" function.  It can also be accomplished through macros in Excel. If you don't know macros, a more rudimentary approach is to:

1. create a new sheet and paste all the values of your first column (assuming this is a column you want to keep) as the first column in the new worksheet (column A).  Now, in column B, paste the name of the ***first column header that you want to be value in a column.  For example, below you want the column header 'red' to be in it's own column - maybe a "color" column. Drag 'red' down column B for every row where you have a unique record in column A.
2. Then, underneath this- paste all the values in column A again, while
   pasting in column B the ***second*** column that you want to perform
   "columns to text" on ('orange' in the below example).
3. Repeat for however many columns that you need
   to list as "text".
4. Finally, in column C, use the values that you have in column A and column B and create an index(match(match()) to find out what value is at the intersection of the two values you have in column A and column B.

Here's an example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Really like the elegance of this approach, and doesn't require VBA!

Answer (score 0):

Excel help offers this technique:

> Given you are combining cell A1 and B1
>
> In the new cell, enter
>
> `=(A1&" "&B1)`
>
> *{{Note the space between the apostrophes}}*

I used this to insert filler text as well, so mine read `=(P2&", also"&Q2)`.