# How can I convert columns into a single, pipe-separated column without losing scientific notation?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have used [this VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19192794/283650) to convert columns into pipe separated format. However, the data contains numbers in scientific notation (eg `2.000000e-01`) which Excel automatically converts into `0.2` which I don't want.

I have tried changing this code:

```
var = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Value))
```

into

```
var = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng))
```

or even

```
var = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Text))
```

neither of which work. I've also tried formatting the cells all to Text (the macro then gives a `Value` error) or even [switching off scientific notation](https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel).

How can I convert columns into a single, pipe-separated column without losing scientific notation?

Sample columns:

```
SAMPLE  TEST    2.000000e-01    2.000000e-01
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misread the post. This answer is for separating text from one column into many columns. OP is trying the reverse.

You use the Excel Text to Columns wizard (on the Data tab, select Text to Columns). Select your data, then run click the menu. When you get to step 3, tell Excel that you want to keep the column as Text.

[image: Step 3 Of Text to Columns wizard]

If you need this done using VBA, then use the macro recorder to get the initial code which you can then tweak to fit your needs.

Comment: Great idea but unfortunately that did not work. It still removes the scientific notation format!

Comment: It worked for me on test data. Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: Ah, I beg your pardon. In the cell it *displays* 2.00E-01 but if I look in the formula bar it has already converted it to *0.2*! I will do more experimenting and get back to you. (It's like Excel is out to get me! ;) )

Comment: Wait a sec... you're doing Text To Columns (which I need to do before, this step, coincidentally, that's why I went along with this) but this question is about converting multiple columns. I will post example data.

Comment: My mistake - I misread your post. You want to **join** columns into one column as pipe-separated values. I thought you were doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You want to concatenate text values using either the `CONCATENATE` function or the `&` operator. For the scientific notation, you want to use the `TEXT` function. Excel is actually storing the numbers as 0.2 but then displaying them in scientific notation.

The help for the `TEXT` function says:

> Syntax: TEXT(value, format_text)
>   Display scientific notations:
>   To display numbers in scientific (exponential) format, use the following exponent codes in the format_text argument.E (E-, E+, e-, e+) Displays a number in scientific (exponential) format. Excel displays a number to the right of the "E" or "e" that corresponds to the number of places that the decimal point was moved. For example, if the format_text argument is "0.00E+00", Excel displays the number 12,200,000 as 1.22E+07. If you change the format_text argument to "#0.0E+0", Excel displays 12.2E+6.

So for your example, assuming the values are in cells A1:D1, use:

```
=A1&"|"&B1&"|"&TEXT(C1,"0.000000E+00")&"|"&TEXT(D1,"0.000000E+00")
```

Or in VBA, you can use the `Text` property of the `Range` object to get the contents of the cell *as they are displayed.* If the column width is too narrow for a date and the column shows "########" then that is what the `Text` property will return.

Comment: You wrote *"Or in VBA, you can use the Text property of the Range object"*. However, in the question I stated that I had tried `rng.Text` - was that what you meant?

Comment: The VBA function in your post does fail. Probably because it is using the `Transpose` function. If you build the string in VBA by looping through the cells and appending the `.Text` value to a string it should be fine, e.g. `myString = myString & "|" & cell.Text` . Or use the Excel function in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm afraid it will be a few days before I can test this - will get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I've decided to implement this in a different way; cannot work this out easily. Apologies for inconvenience and thanks for your help.